# JQuery get whole form not just innerHtml by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an issue with AJAX and CakePHP at the moment, so I am trying to work a little magic, basically, I have an element that I am grabbing that contains a form, when I echo the element, I am echoing it inside another form, so I end up with nested forms... I want to use jquery to grab the entire form that is nested and move it outside the form it is nested in.

I tried using

```
var frm = $('#prevmdform').html();
$('#prevmdform').remove();
$('#hiddenpreview').html(frm);
```

it only puts the innerHtml into #hiddenpreview... meaning its missing the

```
<form action='post' ..... > .... </form>
```

How do I grab the whole form including the above and not just the innerHtml?

Comment: I searched for something different, and other people might too.... My topic for this question would have fulfilled my search... just link the second one...

Comment: downvoting duplicates is stupid, the topic and contents of the question might bring someone closer to the answer one day if they search for something other than what was in the duplicate, cause the duplicate DID NOT come up in my search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remove function returns the entire contents you want, so use it to populate your temp variable instead of the .html call:

```
var frm = $('#prevmdform').remove();
$('#hiddenpreview').html(frm);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the entire element using `$('#prevmdform')[0].outerHTML`, but Jason P's answer is really the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working with the html, you can just move the element:

```
$('#prevmdform').appendTo('#hiddenpreview');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bvfa4qmp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use  jquery `prepend()` method to add form content into div and then you can remove your form like following.

```js
$("#context").prepend($('#yourForm').html());
$('#yourForm').remove();
console.log($("#context").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="context">
  <form id="yourForm">
     <input type="text" />
  </form>
</div>
```